# Getting a type error converting array using PIL

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, python-imaging-library

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

pixels1 = Image.open('image.jpeg')

pixels = pixels1.load()

for i in range(pixels1.size[0]):
    for j in range(pixels1.size[1]):
        pixels[i,j] = (0, 0, 0)

pixels = np.asarray(pixels)
pixels = Image.fromarray(pixels)
pixels.show()
```

**I get this error**

TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1), |O

Comment: Please share the entire error message. Also, why are you accessing the values individually like that? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pixels` variable is a [PixelAccess object](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/PixelAccess.html#pixelaccess), used to access individual pixels. it is not the pixel data itself. if you want to see the modified image, use the `pixels1` variable.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

pixels1 = Image.open('image.jpg')

pixels = pixels1.load()

for i in range(pixels1.size[0]):
    for j in range(pixels1.size[1]):
        pixels[i,j] = (0, 0, 0)

pixels = np.asarray(pixels1)
pixels = Image.fromarray(pixels)
pixels.show()
```

however I'm not sure why you convert the modified image to an array and then to image again, you can just do `pixels1.show()` after the loop.